# How do I convert a mobile app on my device into an IPA file?

Tags: ios, mobile, ipa, simblee

I've been using an app (Simblee app, to be specific) to manage some software components of a hardware device - an electric motor system. For example, the Simblee ios app is used as the UI to control some of the functionality of the hardware device like turning on the led lights on the device, managing how much power the device outputs, etc .

However, the app is no longer available through the App Store. I can still use the Simblee app on phones where the app has already been installed but I just got a new phone and I cannot use the Simblee through that phone. I saw online that it may be possible to convert the app from a phone to an ipa file. I've tried using iMazing to generate an ipa file but run into issues where the ipa file is corrupt. When I go on diawi to share this app with others, the error I get is: 4001009: Invalid .ipa file: missing embedded mobileprovision.

My question is two-fold:
1) Is there another way to convert the mobile app to an ipa file? 
2) If not, is there a way to fix this error that I'm running into?

Answer (score 0):

A mobile app is distributed via an IPA file. The problem you're facing is app signing. iOS apps are digitally signed by the App store for a specific device. You need to install the app from the app store in order to get it signed for a new device. I don't think there is a way to circumvent that step unless you use a jailbroken phone.

On Mac OS you can copy a Mac app from one Mac to another Mac with that uses the same AppleID in the app store and it will authenticate it and it will work, but I don't think you can do that with iOS apps.

tldr: I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! Doesn't sound great :( Holding onto a glimmer of hope that someone else may have better news.